# Scrollable HTML Table and Javascript Table Body Floats with Vertical Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi all just got an html scrollable table with fixed headers. The table is to scroll vertical and horizontal without moving the scroll bar along with the table body. The source of the code [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/X2Kmd/1/)

the code is below

```js
$('table').on('scroll', function() {
  $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 25px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: block;
}
thead {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
thead,
tbody {
  display: block;
}
tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 140px;
}
td,
th {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border: dashed 1px lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <th>Column 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 6</td>
        <td>Row 6</td>
        <td>Row 6</td>
        <td>Row 6</td>
        <td>Row 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 7</td>
        <td>Row 7</td>
        <td>Row 7</td>
        <td>Row 7</td>
        <td>Row 7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 8</td>
        <td>Row 8</td>
        <td>Row 8</td>
        <td>Row 8</td>
        <td>Row 8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 9</td>
        <td>Row 9</td>
        <td>Row 9</td>
        <td>Row 9</td>
        <td>Row 9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 10</td>
        <td>Row 10</td>
        <td>Row 10</td>
        <td>Row 10</td>
        <td>Row 10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

below is the picture of the my scrollable table.

[image]

And this is the image from the jfiddle page

[image]

I want the table to scroll like in the second picture. Any suggestion